# joining two csv files based on a column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I have 2 csv files as follows

```
AllEmpployees.txt
EmpID,Name

QualifiedEmployeees.csv
Empid
```

Now i want to find names of qualified employees

```
Empid,Name
```

Am using following command

```
   join -t , -1 1 -2 1 QualifiedEmployeees.csv AllEmployees.txt
```

This results in zero records.Am sure that there is a intersection of employeeids.

Reference : https://superuser.com/questions/26834/how-to-join-two-csv-files

Is it because qualified employees file has only one column and there is no delimiter?Or am i doing something wrong

Comment: can you show first few lines' output of `cat -vte AllEmployees.txt` command

Comment: `EmpID` != `Empid`

Comment: what u mean by EmpID != Empid  ? i dont have headers in my csv.that was just for explanation

Comment: Not sure why my question is downvoted.This is not good.I have provided completed details about the issue am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
join -t "," <(dos2unix <QualifiedEmployeees.csv) <(dos2unix <AllEmpployees.txt)
```

Comment: Worked!Thanks.But its producing duplicate records as fullEmployess.txt has duplicate records

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce this with your example.

Comment: @AbuShoeb: I suggest you start a new question with an example.

Comment: @Cyrus I just did. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If `join` is not working (not producing as many rows as you expect, or no rows at all), it is likely because your input is not sorted.  From `man join` we see this:

> When the default field delimiter characters are used, the files to be joined should be ordered in the
>        collating sequence of sort(1), using the -b option, on the fields on which they are to be joined, oth-
>        erwise join may not report all field matches.  When the field delimiter characters are specified by the
>        -t option, the collating sequence should be the same as sort(1) without the -b option.

Comment: my data is sorted.Plz check real data example in the edited post

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $2}' Qualiedemployees.txt allEmployees.txt
```